# How can I replace a character with a "new line" in LibreOffice Calc?

Tags: newline, libreoffice-calc

For example I have:

`Line 1 * Line 2 * Line 3`

and want to replace all `*`s in my document with "new line" to get this:

`Line1`
`Line2`
`Line3`

Is this possible?

Answer (score 7):

Since unchecking Wildcards in my Find & Replace seems to make no difference, you seem to have two choices, other than a script:

1) Manually select each `*` and

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>

or

2) Apply a formula to create a separate version of your data:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(A1," * ",CHAR(10))
```